# Best practise to handle with responses and incoming props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

with redux, we uses actions to handle with crud operations. But I stuck at some points. If we send async requests inside of component. We can easly handle with response. But when we send request through actions, we dont know what happened. Is request send successfully ? it took how much amount of time ? What kind of response is returned ? we don't know that

I will clarify question with samples..

lets update a post.

```
onClick () {
    postsApi.post(this.state.post)        | we know how much time
        .then(res => res.data)            | has took to execute
        .then(res => {                    | request 
            console.log(res) // we have the response 
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(error))
}
```

But if we use actions

```
onClick () {
    this.props.updatePost(this.state.post)  // we know nothing what will happen
}
```

or handling with incoming props. lets say I have fetchPost() action to retrieve post

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchPost()
}
```

`render` method and `componentDidUpdate`  will run as well. It's cool. But what if I want to update my state by incoming props ? I can't do this operation inside of `componentDidUpdate` method. it causes infinity loop.

If I use componentWillUpdate method, well, things works fine but I'm getting this warning.

> Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not
>   recommended for use.  Move data fetching code or side effects to
>   componentDidUpdate. If you're updating state whenever props change,
>   refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static
>   getDerivedStateFromProps

I can't use `componentDidUpdate` method for infinty loop. Neither `getDerivedStateFromProps` method because it's run everytime when state change.

Should I continue to use `componentWillMethod` ? Otherwise what should I use and why (why `componentWillMethod` is unsafe ?)

Comment: Why can't we understand  what happened if we use redux actions? You will update the store in action with some success or error info, and then you will be able to access those values inside your connected component. Show us your action code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correcty, what you would like to do is to **safely** change your local state **only when** your e.g. `updatePost` was successful.

If indeed that is your case, you can pass a callback function on your `updatePost` and call this as long as your update was succefull.

```js
successfulUpdate() {
 // do your thing
   this.setState( ... );
}
onClick () {
   this.props.updatePost(this.state.post, this.successfulUpdate)  // we know nothing what will happen
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also keep in mind that if your action returns a **promise**, then you can just use the `then` method:

```js
onClick () {
   this.props.updatePost(this.state.post).then(this.onFulfilled, this.onRejected)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use redux-thunk in this cases. What if we dispatch an async function instead of dispatch an action object?

Answer (score 0):

*"Neither getDerivedStateFromProps method because it's run everytime when state change."* - does it matter? You can avoid setting state with every `getDerivedStateFromProps` call by using a simple condition inside.

Example:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
   if (props.post !== state.post) { // or anything else
     return {
        post: props.post,
     };
   }

   return null;
};
```

An infinite loop will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way for such cases. We can redux-thunk for asynchronous calls such as api call. What if we define the action that returns promise? Please check the code below.

```js
actions.js

export const GetTodoList = dispatch => {
  return Axios.get('SOME_URL').then(res => {
    // dispatch some actions
    
    // return result
    return res.data;
  });
}

TodoList.js

onClick = async () => {
  const { GetTodoList } = this.props;
  try {
    const data = await GetTodoList();
    // handler for success
    this.setState({
      success: true,
      data
    });
  } catch {
    // handler for failure
    this.setState({
      success: fail,
      data: null
    });
  }
    
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  GetTodoList
});
```

So we can use actions like API(which returns promise) thanks to redux-thunk.
Let me know your opinion.